# CGAL, Advancing front surface reconstruction algorithm not ending

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal

so I am trying to construct a mesh from an unstructured set of points with CGAL:Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction.

However, when it works in some cases, I appears that the function never ends in some other cases and I don't know why.

I use it in a for loop. It works fine for X iterations (X varies each time), the algorithm is fast (less than 1s) but then it gets stuck at one iteration.
No segmentation fault, no error. Just the algorithm running and never ending.
I tried letting it run for an hour, nothing.

Any clue ?

Edits: more explanations of what I do.

I am trying to implement [this paper](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~dcor/articles/2015/generalized.cylinder.pdf) and especially the part profile variation calculation (part 3 of the paper).

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef K::Point_3  Point_3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3> CGAL_Mesh;
typedef std::vector<K::Point_3> Polyline_type;
typedef std::vector<Polyline_type > Polylines;

float GC::generateApproximatedProfileCurves(Vector_vector_points profiles_samples){

   float epsilon = 0.01f;
   int nb_profiles = aligned_profiles.size();

   if( nb_profiles < 1){
       return 0.0f;
   }

   std::vector<Point_3> control_profiles;
   // Vector to check if a profile has already been added to the approximated shape
   std::vector<bool> control_profiles_indices(nb_profiles, false);

   // Initialization of the approximated shape with start and end profiles
   std::vector<Point_3> cs_points(Utils::getAllPoints(aligned_profiles[0]));
   control_profiles.insert(control_profiles.end(), cs_points.begin(), cs_points.end());
   control_profiles_indices[0] = true;
   std::vector<Point_3> ce_points(Utils::getAllPoints(aligned_profiles[nb_profiles-1]));
   control_profiles.insert(control_profiles.end(), ce_points.begin(), ce_points.end());
   control_profiles_indices[nb_profiles-1] = true;

   bool done = false;
   float sumDist = 0.0f;

   while( !done ){
       // Generation of the approximated shape from the points of the control profiles
       CGAL_Mesh approximated_shape = Utils::generateMesh(control_profiles);

       float max_dist = 0.0f;
       int max_index = -1;
       for(int i = 1; i < nb_profiles-1; i++){

           if( !control_profiles_indices[i]){

               Point_3 profile_centroid = aligned_centroids[i];
               // Conversion from Point_3 to Vec3f
               Vec3f v_profile_centroid(profile_centroid.x(), profile_centroid.y(), profile_centroid.z());
               // Computation of the corresponding profile on the approximated shape
               Polylines approx_profile(Utils::cross_section(Vec3f(0,1,0), v_profile_centroid, approximated_shape));
               // Gets points of this corresponding profile
               std::vector<Point_3> approx_profile_samples(sampleProfileCurve(approx_profile, nb_profile_samples));
               // Distance between profile and his corresponding profile
               float dist = Utils::Haussdorf(profiles_samples[i], approx_profile_samples);

               if( dist > max_dist){

                   max_dist = dist;
                   max_index = i;
               }
           }
       }
       // If max_dist > epsilon, adds the profile to the control profiles
       if((max_dist > epsilon) && (max_index != -1)){

           sumDist += max_dist;
           control_profiles_indices[max_index] = true;
           // Adds points of the profiles to be added to the vector of control_profiles
           std::vector<Point_3> control_prfl_points(Utils::getAllPoints(aligned_profiles[max_index]));
           control_profiles.insert(control_profiles.end(), control_prfl_points.begin(),
                                                control_prfl_points.end());
           approximated_shape.clear();
       }else{
           done = true;
       }
   }

   return sumDist;
}
```

The profiles avec stored is the aligned_profiles vector. The centroids in aligned centroids. And the samples for each profile in profiles_samples (vector< vector> ).

The original point set is 
Thanks

Here is the function Utils::generateMesh, code is from CGAL examples

```
static CGAL_Mesh generateMesh(std::vector<Point_3> points){

      CGAL_Mesh m;
      Construct construct(m,points.begin(),points.end());
      CGAL::advancing_front_surface_reconstruction(points.begin(),
                                                   points.end(),
                                                   construct);

      return m;
}
```

The [point set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/30exmvv4escxkdo/hand_points.txt?dl=0) is a surface sampling of [this mesh](https://www.dropbox.com/s/szsw4rn7jwoalsl/hand.off?dl=0)

Comment: Put the .cpp and the point set somewhere so that we can have a look.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @AndreasFabri, I've add more infos on my post

Comment: I think you should dump the point cloud that is making the code looping (the algorithm is working for me with the point set provided).